# issue with inserting data to table view in ios

Tags: ios, ios5, uitableview

I have developed a application where i am fetching data from core data and i am displaying it in a table view. I got everything fine until fetching the data but while inserting them to table view only the last entry is displaying in the table view. Below is the code i have written please preview and help me to get the solution.

```
 Deviceinfo *app = [arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
switch(indexPath.row)
{


case 0:  
        NSLog(@"%@",app.platform);
        cell.textLabel.text = @"platform";
        cell.detailTextLabel.text =[app platform];

case 1:
        NSLog(@"%@",app.model);
        cell.textLabel.text = @"model";
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [app model];
case 2:
        NSLog(@"%@",app.mac_address);
        cell.textLabel.text = @"mac address";
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [app mac_address]; 
}
return cell;
```

I implement this code in the cellForRowAtIndexpath delegate. I am getting only the mac address in table view. hoping for better solution

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert break statements after each case, otherwise the case will just fall though to the next one

```
switch(x) {
    case 1:
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Based on your additional comments, try something like the following: Each device will have its own table view section and each section will have 3 table view rows, one for each piece of information.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return devices.count
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 3;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{        
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[FEMenuItemInfoCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];            
    }    

    Device *device = [devices objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            cell.textLabel.text = @"platform";
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = [device platform]; 
            break;            
        case 1:
            cell.textLabel.text = @"model";
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = [device mac_address]; 
            break;
        case 2:
            cell.textLabel.text = @"mac address";
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = [device mac_address]; 
            break;                        
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: but i need all the three case to be executed. If i insert break after executing first case control exits loop right how the remaining cases executes

Comment: i need all the cases should execute and display its contents in different cells.

Comment: you'll need to use multiple cells on multiple rows.  Hold on i'll update it with the proper code for your case.

Comment: You need to create a cell for each identifier (platform, model, mac_address) or create a custom cell that will hold all 3 values